# How to pass to gcc "-lregex"?

Tags: gcc, linker, ld

I want to compile a program,bacula under hpux
but give me an error about "unsatisfied symbol"
i think probably passing the correct lib "-lregex"
will solve the problem.
But i don't know how to pass to linker (is a ld error)
i have tried LDFLAGS="-lregex" but didn't work(give me gcc
cannot create executables)
I also tried to add to LIBS of makefile the -lregex
but nothing change

This is the full error

```
libtool --silent --tag=CXX --mode=link /usr/local/bin/g++   -L../lib -L../findlib -o bacula-fd filed.o authenticate.o acl.o backup.o estimate.o  fd_plugins.o accurate.o  filed_conf.o heartbeat.o job.o pythonfd.o  restore.o status.o verify.o verify_vol.o xattr.o \
         -lbacfind -lbacpy -lbaccfg -lbac -lm  -lpthread  \
         -lssl -lcrypto   
ld: Unsatisfied symbol "regerror(int, re_pattern_buffer const*, char*, unsigned long)" in file job.o
ld: (Warning) Unsatisfied symbol "regexec(re_pattern_buffer const*, char const*, unsigned long, regmatch_t*, int)" in file /home/giuseppe/bacula/bin/bacula-5.2.13/src/findlib/.libs/libbacfind.so
ld: Unsatisfied symbol "regcomp(re_pattern_buffer*, char const*, int)" in file job.o
ld: (Warning) Unsatisfied symbol "posix_fadvise(int, long long, long long, int)" in file /home/giuseppe/bacula/bin/bacula-5.2.13/src/lib/.libs/libbac.so
ld: Unsatisfied symbol "regfree(re_pattern_buffer*)" in file job.o
2 warnings.
3 errors.
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Codice di uscita errore 1
```

Comment: What about `CFLAGS=-lregex` ?

Comment: Will try tomorrow

Comment: Works with make LDFLAGS='-lregex' now give another error.If you add this as answer i can vote it.